# More rows than intended when calling DataFrames by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have two different files. z_df and s_df. Their first column is the same (it is timepoint). Each row is a unique time instance.

Now I want to build a classifier on z_df and s_df separately. That is fine. But the problem is that I want to use same indexing for their training and testing set. For instance, if the first four rows of z_df was selected for training then the first 4 rows of s_df must be selected as well.

```
    z_df.shape, s_df.shape:
   ((450865, 5), (450865, 930))

   train_df, test_df = train_test_split(z_df, test_size=TEST_SIZE, shuffle=True )



    train_df.shape:
    (315605, 5)


    m=train_df[0].tolist()
    len(m), train_df.shape:
    (315605, (315605, 5))

    s_train=s_df[s_df[0].isin(m)]
    s_train.shape, train_df.shape:
    ((362774, 930), (315605, 5))
```

As you can see number of rows for s_train is different from that of train_df. Why?? I used the first column to call them. Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: neither `train_df[0]` nor `s_df[s_df[0].isin(m)]` is *calling DataFrames by index*.

Comment: @QuangHoang You re right. This calls the DataFrames by its  first column . But that should work too. Their first column is the same

Comment: Are you sure the values in s_df[0] are unique? What’s `len(s_df[0].unique()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang You got it! Thank you for the help. Please answer the question in the page so I can confirm this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because your `s_df[0]` contains duplicates. This can be confirmed by `len(s_df[0]) == len(s_df[0].unique())`.

To sample both data sets:

```
is_train = np.random.choice((True, False), size=len(s_df), p=(0.7, 0.3))

s_train, z_train = s_df[is_train], z_df[is_train]
s_test, z_test = s_df[~is_train], z_df[~is_train]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I should have asked here sooner :) . Took 2 hours for me without no avail.